# Using VSCode for Unity - Project loading failed

Tags: unity-game-engine, visual-studio-code, omnisharp

I'm Trying to use VSCode as my Unity code editor and I followed this [Unity Development with VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/other/unity)

At first the project loading error told me to install .net framework 4.7.1 so I installed that. The intellisense works fine for me now, but now I get this big error message. It still shows the same error but now without the part that tells to install the sdk.

```
Status: failed to load

Error: Build started. Project "Assembly-CSharp.csproj" (ResolveAssemblyReferencesDesignTime;ResolveProjectReferencesDesignTime;ResolvePackageDependenciesDesignTime;_GenerateCompileDependencyCache;_ComputeNonExistentFileProperty;CoreCompile target(s)): Target "AssignProjectConfiguration" skipped, due to false condition; ('$(CurrentSolutionConfigurationContents)' != '' or '@(ProjectReference)'!='') was evaluated as ('' != '' or ''!=''). Target "_SplitProjectReferencesByFileExistence" in file "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.101\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets" from project "d:\Docs\Unity\oncemore\Assembly-CSharp.csproj" (target "PrepareProjectReferences" depends on it): Task "ResolveNonMSBuildProjectOutput" skipped, due to false condition; ('$(BuildingInsideVisualStudio)'=='true' and '@(ProjectReferenceWithConfiguration)'!='') was evaluated as (''=='true' and ''!=''). Done building target "_SplitProjectReferencesByFileExistence" in project "Assembly-CSharp.csproj". Target "_AddOutputPathToGlobalPropertiesToRemove" in file "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.101\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets" from project "d:\Docs\Unity\oncemore\Assembly-CSharp.csproj" (target "_GetProjectReferenceTargetFrameworkProperties" depends on it): Done building target "_AddOutputPathToGlobalPropertiesToRemove" in project "Assembly-CSharp.csproj". Target "_GetProjectReferenceTargetFrameworkProperties" in file "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.101\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets" from project "d:\Docs\Unity\oncemore\Assembly-CSharp.csproj" (target "PrepareProjectReferences" depends on it): Using "MSBuild" task from assembly "Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Core, Version=15.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a". Task "MSBuild" Done executing task "MSBuild". Task "GetReferenceNearestTargetFrameworkTask" skipped, due to false condition; ('@(_ProjectReferenceTargetFrameworkPossibilities)' != '' and '$(ReferringTargetFrameworkForProjectReferences)' != '' And '$(GetReferenceNearestTargetFrameworkTaskSupportsTargetPlatformParameter)'
== 'true' and '%(_ProjectReferenceTargetFrameworkPossibilities.IsVcxOrNativeProj)' != 'true') was evaluated as ('' != '' and '.NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1' != '' And 'true' == 'true' and '' != 'true'). Task "GetReferenceNearestTargetFrameworkTask" skipped, due to false condition; ('@(_ProjectReferenceTargetFrameworkPossibilities)' != '' and '$(ReferringTargetFrameworkForProjectReferences)' != '' And '$(GetReferenceNearestTargetFrameworkTaskSupportsTargetPlatformParameter)' != 'true' and '%(_ProjectReferenceTargetFrameworkPossibilities.IsVcxOrNativeProj)' != 'true') was evaluated as ('' != '' and '.NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1' != '' And 'true' != 'true' and '' != 'true'). Done building target "_GetProjectReferenceTargetFrameworkProperties" in project "Assembly-CSharp.csproj". Target "_GetProjectReferencePlatformProperties" skipped, due to false condition; ('$(EnableDynamicPlatformResolution)' == 'true' and '$(BuildingInsideVisualStudio)' != 'true' and '@(_MSBuildProjectReferenceExistent)' != '') was evaluated as ('' == 'true' and '' != 'true' and '' != ''). Target "PrepareProjectReferences" in file "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.101\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets" from project "d:\Docs\Unity\oncemore\Assembly-CSharp.csproj" (target "ResolveProjectReferences" depends on it): Done building target "PrepareProjectReferences" in project "Assembly-CSharp.csproj". Target "ResolveProjectReferences" in file "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.101\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets" from project "d:\Docs\Unity\oncemore\Assembly-CSharp.csproj" (target "ResolveAssemblyReferencesDesignTime" depends on it): Task "MSBuild" skipped, due to false condition; ('%(_MSBuildProjectReferenceExistent.BuildReference)' == 'true' and '@(ProjectReferenceWithConfiguration)' != '' and ('$(BuildingInsideVisualStudio)' == 'true' or '$(BuildProjectReferences)' != 'true') and '$(VisualStudioVersion)' != '10.0' and '@(_MSBuildProjectReferenceExistent)' != '') was evaluated as ('' == 'true' and '' != '' and ('' == 'true' or 'false' != 'true') and '17.0' != '10.0' and '' != ''). Task "MSBuild" skipped, due to false condition; ('%(_MSBuildProjectReferenceExistent.BuildReference)'
== 'true' and '@(ProjectReferenceWithConfiguration)' != '' and '$(BuildingInsideVisualStudio)' != 'true' and '$(BuildProjectReferences)' == 'true' and '@(_MSBuildProjectReferenceExistent)' != '') was evaluated as ('' == 'true' and '' != '' and '' != 'true' and 'false' == 'true' and '' != ''). Task "MSBuild" skipped, due to false condition; ('%(_MSBuildProjectReferenceExistent.BuildReference)' == 'true' and '@(ProjectReferenceWithConfiguration)' != '' and '$(BuildingProject)'
== 'true' and '@(_MSBuildProjectReferenceExistent)' != '') was evaluated as ('' == 'true' and '' != '' and 'false' == 'true' and '' != ''). Task "Warning" skipped, due to false condition; ('@(ProjectReferenceWithConfiguration)' != '' and '@(_MSBuildProjectReferenceNonexistent)' != '') was evaluated as ('' != '' and '' != ''). Done building target "ResolveProjectReferences" in project "Assembly-CSharp.csproj". Target "ResolveProjectReferences" skipped. Previously built successfully. Target "FindInvalidProjectReferences" skipped, due to false condition; ('$(FindInvalidProjectReferences)' == 'true') was evaluated as ('' == 'true'). Target "GetFrameworkPaths" in file "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.101\Microsoft.NETFramework.CurrentVersion.targets" from project "d:\Docs\Unity\oncemore\Assembly-CSharp.csproj" (target "ResolveAssemblyReferences" depends on it): Done building target "GetFrameworkPaths" in project "Assembly-CSharp.csproj". Target "GetFrameworkPaths" skipped. Previously built successfully. Target "GetReferenceAssemblyPaths" in file "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.101\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets" from project "d:\Docs\Unity\oncemore\Assembly-CSharp.csproj" (target "ResolveAssemblyReferences" depends on it): Using "GetReferenceAssemblyPaths" task from assembly "Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Core, Version=15.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a". Task "GetReferenceAssemblyPaths" Done executing task "GetReferenceAssemblyPaths". Done building target "GetReferenceAssemblyPaths" in project "Assembly-CSharp.csproj". Target "GetFrameworkPaths" skipped. Previously built successfully. Target "GetReferenceAssemblyPaths" skipped. Previously built successfully. Target "AssignLinkMetadata" skipped, due to false condition; ( '$(SynthesizeLinkMetadata)' == 'true' ) was evaluated as ( '' == 'true' ). Target "PrepareForBuild" in file "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.101\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets" from project "d:\Docs\Unity\oncemore\Assembly-CSharp.csproj" (target "ResolveAssemblyReferences" depends on it): Using "FindAppConfigFile" task from assembly "Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Core, Version=15.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a". Task "FindAppConfigFile" Done executing task "FindAppConfigFile". Using "MakeDir" task from assembly "Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Core, Version=15.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a". Task "MakeDir" Creating directory "Temp\bin\Debug\". Done executing task "MakeDir". Done building target "PrepareForBuild" in project "Assembly-CSharp.csproj". Target "GetInstalledSDKLocations" skipped, due to false condition; ('@(SDKReference)' != '') was evaluated as ('' != ''). Target "ResolveSDKReferences" in file "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.101\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets" from project "d:\Docs\Unity\oncemore\Assembly-CSharp.csproj" (target "ResolveAssemblyReferences" depends on it): Task "ResolveSDKReference" skipped, due to false condition; ('@(SDKReference)'!='') was evaluated as (''!=''). Done building target "ResolveSDKReferences" in project "Assembly-CSharp.csproj". Target "ResolveSDKReferences" skipped. Previously built successfully. Target "ExpandSDKReferences" in file "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.101\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets" from project "d:\Docs\Unity\oncemore\Assembly-CSharp.csproj" (target "ResolveAssemblyReferences" depends on it): Task "GetSDKReferenceFiles" skipped, due to false condition; ('@(ResolvedSDKReference)'!='') was evaluated as (''!=''). Done building target "ExpandSDKReferences" in project "Assembly-CSharp.csproj". Target "ImplicitlyExpandNETStandardFacades" skipped, due to false condition; ('$(ImplicitlyExpandNETStandardFacades)' == 'true') was evaluated as ('false' == 'true'). Target "GetFrameworkPaths" skipped. Previously built successfully. Target "GetReferenceAssemblyPaths" skipped. Previously built successfully. Target "ImplicitlyExpandNETStandardFacades" skipped, due to false condition; ('$(ImplicitlyExpandNETStandardFacades)' == 'true') was evaluated as ('false' == 'true'). Target "_HandlePackageFileConflicts" in file "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.101\Microsoft\Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions\Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions.ConflictResolution.targets" from project "d:\Docs\Unity\oncemore\Assembly-CSharp.csproj" (target "ResolveAssemblyReferences" depends on it): Using "ResolvePackageFileConflicts" task from assembly "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.101\Microsoft\Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions\\tools\net6.0\Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions.Tasks.dll". Task "ResolvePackageFileConflicts" Encountered conflict between 'Reference:System.IO.Compression' and 'Platform:System.IO.Compression.dll'. Choosing 'Reference:System.IO.Compression' because AssemblyVersion '4.1.3.0' is greater than '4.0.0.0'. Encountered conflict between 'Reference:System.Net.Http' and 'Platform:System.Net.Http.dll'. Choosing 'Reference:System.Net.Http' because AssemblyVersion '4.1.2.0' is greater than '4.0.0.0'. Encountered conflict between 'Reference:mscorlib' and 'Platform:mscorlib.dll'. Could not determine a winner because 'Platform:mscorlib.dll' has no file version. Encountered conflict between 'Reference:System.ComponentModel.Composition' and 'Platform:System.ComponentModel.Composition.dll'. Could not determine a winner because 'Platform:System.ComponentModel.Composition.dll' has no file version. Encountered conflict between 'Reference:System.Core' and 'Platform:System.Core.dll'. Could not determine a winner because 'Platform:System.Core.dll' has no file version.Target "ResolveAssemblyReferences" skipped. Previously built successfully. Target "ResolveProjectReferencesDesignTime" in file "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.101\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets" from project "d:\Docs\Unity\oncemore\Assembly-CSharp.csproj" (entry point): Done building target "ResolveProjectReferencesDesignTime" in project "Assembly-CSharp.csproj". The target "ResolvePackageDependenciesDesignTime" does not exist in the project. Done building project "Assembly-CSharp.csproj" -- FAILED. Build FAILED.
```

I have also installed MSBuild tools to try to fix this but still didn't work out. If anyone has any info regaurding this I would be grateful.

Comment: I download ndp from here https://download.visualstudio.microsoft.com/download/pr/e5eb8d37-5bbd-4fb7-a71d-b749e010ef9f/601437d729667ecd29020a829fbc4881/ndp471-devpack-enu.exe

and then downloaded .net sdk from here
https://download.visualstudio.microsoft.com/download/pr/44069ee2-ce02-41d7-bcc5-2168a1653278/cfc5131c81ae00a5f77f05f9963ec98d/dotnet-sdk-5.0.404-win-x64.exe

After than i restarted my system, i did this 1 day before this question was created hope these 2 softwares help

Comment: It worked for me with `dotnet-sdk-5.0.404-win-x64.exe` sdk

Comment: @silentsudo nope still the same error. I even tried uninstalling sdk v6.0.101 and then running it. Still shows the same error but with the v5.0.404

Comment: @silentsudo could you tell me which version of Unity you're using?

Comment: unity hub 3.0.1 and editor 2020.3.27f1

Comment: Shoot I'm running into this too, LTS 2021.3.22f1. Do you ever solve?